# Zoom on MacOS can't access microphone

Tags: macos

After installing "zoom.us" on my latest-and-greatest Mac, I find that it is not listed in the set of applications that I can grant access to my microphone.

Comment: Go to Zoom (website) and set up a test meeting for yourself. When you join the meeting, there is a Microphone Icon and Camera Icon (for video). Can you turn on the Microphone there?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384310/how-do-i-configure-camera-and-microphone-permission-on-macos-mojave